# TextArea or something in java that converts the formatted String to html

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, html-editor, htmleditorkit

I don't know how to formulate my question correctly, but I am looking for something like this: 
[image]

But I want to save it as html code in the database like this:

```
<html><body><p>here's the "<em>preloaded</em><strong>content</strong>"</p></body></html>
```

Can you recommend a library or component that I can use? Thanks!

Comment: A `JEditorPane` can handle (basic i.e. a subset of 3.2) HTML & CSS (again, very basic). Many Swing components can display HTML (e.g. `JLabel`, `JButton` ..). The `JTextArea` is for plain text only, and is unsuited to the task.

Comment: I believe the documentation for HTMLDocument answers this question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html

Comment: edited the question to make it clearer.. I want to have an editor which allows the user to format the text, then I want the text to be converted to html code